# Typhoon - inject the same instance everywhere

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, ios8, typhoon

I have a class A that is injected in several places. I would like to inject the same instance of A everywhere - sort of a Singleton but with injection.

Is it possible to do that with Typhoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typhoon has three scopes that you can use for this, [TyphoonScopeSingleton](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes#typhoonscopesingleton), [TyphoonScopeLazySingleton](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes#typhoonscopelazysingleton) and [TyphoonScopeWeakSingleton](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes#typhoonscopeweaksingleton).

**To set the scope of a component:**

```
- (PFRootViewController *)rootViewController
{
    definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
}
```

Using this scope gives all the advantages of a singleton, while the DI pattern avoids the drawbacks.

**More on Typhoon Scopes:**

Many DI containers in other languages have the default scope as **singleton**, while in Typhoon the default scope is `TyphoonScopeObjectGraph`. Having a default scope of singleton makes sense for server environments, where the application might service any use-case at a given time.

Meanwhile, Typhoon is targeted at mobile and desktop environments, so the object graph scope is designed to to load an assembly into memory (a view controller example) and then discard it after proceeding to another use-case. Any shared references, such as a circular dependency pointing back to a parent (eg a delegate) will be shared.

Of course, while this is the default there are cases when other scopes are needed. More info can be found in the [scopes section of the user guide](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes).